# Printing an Ellipse to the screen

Tags: java

The following code is meant to produce an ellipse looking figure but it doesnt. 
You have to project the
outline of an ellipse on the grid. the formula for the circle is

```
((x-h)/a)^2 + ((y-h)/b)^2 = 1
```

The code is:

```
public class Question33 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        DrawMeAnEllipse(4,12,6,4); // calling the method
    }

    public static void DrawMeAnEllipse(int posX, int posY, int radiusA, int radiusB)
    {   
        int xaxis = 20;
        int yaxis = 20; //scanning the coordinates

        for (int x=0; x<xaxis; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<yaxis; y++){

                //using equation of ellipse
                int a = Math.abs((posX-x)/radiusA) * ((posX-x)/radiusA);

                int b = Math.abs((posY-y)/radiusB) * ((posY-y)/radiusB);

                int c = Math.abs(a + b);       

                if ( c=1 ) {  //checking if the equation is satisfied
                    System.out.print('#');
                } else {
                    System.out.print(' ') ;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things I'd consider.

1. Watch out for the fact that you are doing integer division (you'll lose precision and maybe get the wrong result)
2. The `if( c =1 )` should be `if(c == 1)`.

Comment: okay i fixed it to be c==1 ( and now it is printing it somewhat correctly but not completely, for example, its missing a couple of points it should be printing on , but the instructions require me to use integers, now how can i cast the int so that even if precision is sacrificed, it'll print an ellipse looking figure to the screen?